# Can't get Remote Desktop connection after editing firewall rule in windows azure virtual machine

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, port, firewall, remote-desktop

I'm using Windows Azure virtual machines. What I did was I have added some new TCP port to inbound and outbound rules in the firewall. After that I can't get the Remote Desktop connection from my PC. But I got Remote Desktop connection from another virtual machine by using the local IP address.

```
My DNS is :xxxx.cloudapp.net:3389.
```

This is the issue I'm facing. What I actually want is to give provision to new ports inbound and outbound rules in windows Azure virtual machines. Any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a programming question but anyway:

```
Nmap scan report for mjsindia.cloudapp.net (13.66.56.229)

PORT     STATE    SERVICE
3389/tcp filtered ms-wbt-server
```

Make sure you have **3389/TCP** open inbound on both the Network Security Group or ACL in the Azure Portal and Windows Firewall (on the VM, for all Firewall profiles - Private/Public/Domain).